# Python even group assigning

Tags: python, random

I am a beginner to python and was working on a random team generator. The issue I've run into is that I am not sure of how to make it generate even teams. The code is below as well as a sample output.

```
import random


def main():
    run = True
    while run:

        try:
            print("Welcome to this group picker, follow the instructions and your groups will be picked.")
            groupnum = int(input("How many groups do you want?"))
            peoplenum = int(input("How many people are there?"))
            print("Okay, assign everyone a number from 0 to", peoplenum - 1, ".")
            nums = []
            for i in range(0, peoplenum):
                nums.append(i)

            for i in nums:
                print("Number", i, "is in group", random.randint(1, groupnum))

            break

        except:
            print("Error, please follow instructions and enter only numbers.")
            break


main()
```

Sample output:

```
 Welcome to this group picker, follow the instructions and your groups
 will be picked.
 How many groups do you want?2 
 How many people are there?8
 Okay, assign everyone a number from 0 to 7 . 
 Number 0 is in group 1 
 Number 1 is in group 2 
 Number 2 is in group 1 
 Number 3 is in group 2 
 Number 4 is in group 1 
 Number 5 is in group 1 
 Number 6 is in group 2 
 Number 7 is in group 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**

```
import random


def main():
    run = True
    while run:

            print("\nWelcome to this group picker, follow the" \
                "instructions and your groups will be picked.\n")

            group_amount = int(input("How many groups do you want?\n"))
            people_amount = int(input("How many people are there?\n"))

            print("\nOkay, assign everyone a number from 1 to " +
                str(people_amount) + " .\n")

            group = list(range(0, group_amount))
            person = list(range(0, people_amount))
            group_size = people_amount / group_amount


            if group_size % 2 != 0:
                reg_group_size = (people_amount - 1) / group_amount
                odd_group_size = ((people_amount - 1) / group_amount) + 1

            for i in group[0:-1]:
               group[i] = reg_group_size

            group[-1] = odd_group_size

            for p in person:
                r = random.randint(0, len(group)-1)
                while group[r] == 0:
                    r = random.randint(0, len(group)-1) 
                person[p] = r + 1
                group[r] -= 1
                print("Person " + str(p + 1) + " is in group " + 
                    str(person[p]) + ".")

main()
```

**Output**

> ```
> (xenial)vash@localhost:~/pcc/12/alien_invasion_2$ python3 helping.py
>
> Welcome to this group picker, follow theinstructions and your groups will be picked.
>
> How many groups do you want?
> 3
> How many people are there?
> 10
>
> Okay, assign everyone a number from 1 to 10 .
>
> Person 1 is in group 3.
> Person 2 is in group 1.
> Person 3 is in group 2.
> Person 4 is in group 2.
> Person 5 is in group 1.
> Person 6 is in group 3.
> Person 7 is in group 2.
> Person 8 is in group 1.
> Person 9 is in group 3.
> Person 10 is in group 3.
> ```

**Comments**

I agree with all said solutions, but I think most of them deviate pretty far from what your original code was.

I tried to remain true to your code while implementing the missing pieces needed to get it to function as you intended and preserving your original output.

The main issue was that the `random.randint` value doesn't account for the availability of space in each group shrinking once a person is assigned a group.

Step 1:

```
        group = list(range(0, group_amount))
        person = list(range(0, people_amount))
        group_size = people_amount / group_amount
```

This creates a lists `group` and `person`, which are the size of their respective amounts. Also, let's create `group_size` which will give us the amount of `person`'s that can be in each `group`.

Step 2:

```
        if group_size % 2 != 0:
            reg_group_size = (people_amount - 1) / group_amount
            odd_group_size = ((people_amount - 1) / group_amount) + 1

        for i in group[0:-1]:
           group[i] = reg_group_size

        group[-1] = odd_group_size
```

Here we address the problem if we have `group`'s of unequal size. This will create all evenly sized `group`'s with the last `group` being able to hold the left over `person`

Step 3:

```
        for p in person:
            r = random.randint(0, len(group)-1)
            while group[r] == 0:
                r = random.randint(0, len(group)-1) 
            person[p] = r + 1
            group[r] -= 1
            print("Person " + str(p + 1) + " is in group " + 
                str(person[p]) + ".")
```

Now the fun part! This loop will assign `person[p]` to a random `group` and then reduce the amount size of that `group` by 1.

Lets break it down:

```
        for p in person:
            r = random.randint(0, len(group)-1)
            while group[r] == 0:
                r = random.randint(0, len(group)-1)
```

We are going to loop through `person` for the entire population we assigned.
Then we select a random `group` to assign `person` to, but we want to make sure that `group[r]` has available space, `while group[r] == 0:` checks to make sure that there is space if not, a new `r` is generated until we find a random `group` that has space available.

```
            person[p] = r + 1
            group[r] -= 1
            print("Person " + str(p + 1) + " is in group " + 
                str(person[p]) + ".")
```

Finally we assign `person[p] = r + 1` this gives `person[p]` a `group` number(using `r + 1` is so we can eliminate a "group 0" since lists start at 0, and for presentation we would like to start at 1). After that the `group[r]`'s value is reduced by 1, accounting for the availability of space decreasing. In the `print` statement again the `+ 1` just is so again we don't refer to anyone as "Person 0."

Hope this helped, I enjoyed working on this!

Answer (score 3):

Using only the standard library, I would solve it like this:

```
import random
from itertools import accumulate


def print_groups(n, g):
    # Prepare group separators
    size = n // g
    rem = n % g
    separators = list(accumulate([0] + [size+1] * rem + [size] * (g - rem)))

    # Make raw data
    items = list(range(n))
    random.shuffle(items)

    # Iterate and print
    for i, s in enumerate(zip(separators, separators[1:])):
        group = items[slice(*s)]
        print(f'Group {i+1}: {group} (size {len(group)})')
```

If your number of people is divisible by your number of groups, all groups will be the same size, otherwise the first `n % g` groups get one extra member.

Example 1:

```
print_groups(12, 4)

Group 1: [6, 11, 10] (size 3)
Group 2: [7, 2, 5] (size 3)
Group 3: [3, 1, 9] (size 3)
Group 4: [4, 8, 0] (size 3)
```

Example 2:

```
print_groups(14, 4)

Group 1: [8, 3, 4, 6] (size 4)
Group 2: [1, 11, 0, 12] (size 4)
Group 3: [7, 5, 9] (size 3)
Group 4: [13, 10, 2] (size 3)
```

Comment: You can also use `divmod` to do `n % g` and `n // g` in a single line

Answer (score 1):

The problem is randomly picking a team for each player. As [`random.randint`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randint) produces equally distributed values, each player has the same chance of being assigned to any given team, so you can end up with everyone in the same team.

Instead you should consider iterating over the teams and assigning a random player to it.

A poor implementation of that idea would go like

```
>>> import random
>>> 
>>> groupnum = 2
>>> peoplenum = 8
>>> 
>>> people = [i for i in range(peoplenum)]
>>> 
>>> for i in range(peoplenum):
...     group = i % groupnum
...     person = random.choice(people)
...     people.remove(person)
...     print('Number {} assigned to {}'.format(person, group))
... 
Number 6 assigned to 0
Number 7 assigned to 1
Number 4 assigned to 0
Number 3 assigned to 1
Number 2 assigned to 0
Number 5 assigned to 1
Number 1 assigned to 0
Number 0 assigned to 1
```

It will solve the problem, but it relies on calling `remove` to avoid repeating the team members. To avoid this you can shuffle the players list (making it random) and [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=zip#zip) the results with the teams list.

```
>>> import random
>>>
>>> players = [i for i in range(peoplenum)]
>>> teams = [i for i in range(groupnum)]
>>> 
>>> random.shuffle(players)
>>> 
>>> [x for x in zip(players, teams)]
[(7, 0), (5, 1)]
```

This clearly does not work. That is because zip will stop when the shortest iterator stops, in our case `groups`. What we want is to have it repeat while there are players. We can achieve such functionality with [`itertools.cycle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle):

```
>>> import random
>>> import itertools
>>> 
>>> players = [i for i in range(peoplenum)]
>>> teams = itertools.cycle(range(groupnum))
>>> 
>>> random.shuffle(players)
>>> 
>>> [x for x in zip(players, teams)]
[(7, 0), (2, 1), (0, 0), (1, 1), (5, 0), (4, 1), (3, 0), (6, 1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Adjust the probability of each group according to the number of groups. Use a while loop that continually assigns groups and only returns once the groups have equal sum.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this using numpy.random.choice, with replace set to false.
[See relevant numpy documentation here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html)

Try playing with this code:

```
import numpy as np

def assign_people_to_teams(people_count = 8, team_count = 2):
    """
        selects people_count random numbers in the range 0 to people_count-1 without replacement
        then make a team assignment decision based on desired number of teams.
    """
    return [
        element % team_count for element in list(
            np.random.choice(
                people_count,
                people_count,
                replace=False
            )
        )
    ]

team_assignment = assign_people_to_teams()

print(team_assignment)
```

Result:

```
[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use a set for each group and then select the random group for the person. Once each group maxed out, then repeat until all groups are filled in.

```
import random
import sys


def main():
    while True:

        try:
            print("Welcome to this group picker, follow the instructions and your groups will be picked.")
            groupnum = int(input("How many groups do you want?"))
            peoplenum = int(input("How many people are there?"))
            if groupnum == 'Q':
                sys.exit(0)
            print("Okay, assign everyone a number from 1 to", peoplenum, ".")

            nums = []
            for i in range(1, peoplenum+1):
                nums.append(i)

            ''' Validate number of people vs groups '''
            if peoplenum % groupnum:
                print("error: You have incorrect number of people to divide them equally")
                sys.exit(1)

            ''' People per team '''
            peoplePerTeam = int(peoplenum/groupnum)

            ''' Initialize the group'''
            group = {}
            for i in range(1,groupnum+1):
                group[i] = set()

            ''' Loop through the people'''
            for person in nums:
                while True:
                    ''' Find random team '''
                    randomGroup = random.randint(1,groupnum)

                    ''' If team is not filled up yet, then add otherwise find a new team'''
                    if len(group[randomGroup]) < peoplePerTeam:
                        group[randomGroup].add(person)
                        break

            ''' Display the team info'''    
            for i in range(1,groupnum+1):
                print("Team %s members are %s" %(i, group[i]))

        except:
            print("Error, please follow instructions and enter only numbers.")
            break


main()
```

The sample run of this program's output is given below:

```
Welcome to this group picker, follow the 
instructions and your groups will be picked.
How many groups do you want?2
How many people are there?8
Okay, assign everyone a number from 1 to 8 .
**Team 1 members are {1, 2, 5, 7}**
**Team 2 members are {8, 3, 4, 6}**
Welcome to this group picker, follow the 
instructions and your groups will be picked.
How many groups do you want?4
How many people are there?20
Okay, assign everyone a number from 1 to 20 .
**Team 1 members are {1, 18, 19, 20, 17}**
**Team 2 members are {16, 13, 11, 5, 7}**
**Team 3 members are {10, 9, 2, 3, 4}**
**Team 4 members are {8, 12, 15, 6, 14}**
Welcome to this group picker, follow the instructions and your groups will be picked.
```